# How to compile Microsoft SQL server driver in gradle?

Tags: sql-server, gradle

In order to use a SQL server database in my Gradle project I need to add a line in my dependencies to compile or implement it, as adding the drivers to my modules doesn't work because Gradle overwrites them. what should I compile/implement?

Comment: What sort of project is this?

Comment: It's a Discord bot that uses Gradle to use the discord API, and I'd like to use a SQL database to store information in case of a power cut/the bot crashes. Since I'm using Gradle, I need to add something to the build.gradle file's dependencies but I'm not sure what specifically. I'd assume i need to use the compile or implentation commands but I'm not sure what to do specifically.

Comment: Are you trying to use Gradle to deploy a Microsoft SQL database?

Comment: I'd like to read and write to an existing database.

Comment: What language is your project written in?